# How to calculate the sum of the multiples of two fractions in order?

Tags: combinatorics, fractions

$\frac{a}{b_1}, \frac{a}{b_2} = \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{5}$

$x_1 \in \{0, ..., b_1-1\} = \{0, 1, 2\}$

$x_2 \in \{0, ..., b_2-1\} = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$

$$\frac{a_1}{b}, \frac{a_2}{b} = \frac{a_1b_2}{b_1b_2}, \frac{a_2b_1}{b_1b_2} = \frac{5}{15}, \frac{3}{15}$$

$$\frac{p}{q} = \frac{a_1x_1}{b} + \frac{a_2x_2}{b}$$

I've been struggling for a couple of days to find an equation that can calculate $\frac{p}{q}$ in order from smallest to largest. Any help will be appreciated thank you.

The sums in order:

$$\frac{5\cdot0 + 3\cdot0}{15} = \frac{0}{15}, \frac{5\cdot0 + 3\cdot1}{15} = \frac{3}{15}, \frac{5\cdot1 + 3\cdot0}{15} = \frac{5}{15}, \frac{5\cdot0 + 3\cdot2}{15} = \frac{6}{15}$$

$$\frac{5\cdot1 + 3\cdot1}{15} = \frac{8}{15}, \frac{5\cdot0 + 3\cdot3}{15} = \frac{9}{15}, \frac{5\cdot2 + 3\cdot0}{15} = \frac{10}{15}, \frac{5\cdot1 + 3\cdot2}{15} = \frac{11}{15}$$

$$\frac{5\cdot0 + 3\cdot4}{15} = \frac{12}{15}, \frac{5\cdot2 + 3\cdot1}{15} = \frac{13}{15}, \frac{5\cdot1 + 3\cdot3}{15} = \frac{14}{15}, \frac{5\cdot2 + 3\cdot2}{15} = \frac{16}{15}$$

$$\frac{5\cdot1 + 3\cdot4}{15} = \frac{17}{15}, \frac{5\cdot2 + 3\cdot3}{15} = \frac{19}{15}, \frac{5\cdot2 + 3\cdot4}{15} = \frac{22}{15}$$

Comment: Why don't you want to compute them all and then sort them?  You can organize the computation us use the fact that subgroups are presorted.

Comment: @RossMillikan Because I'm not writing s computer program

Comment: Then you can just make a list for each $x_1$ going over the values of $x_2$, so you get $(0,3,6,9,12), (5,8,11,14,17), (10,13,16,19,22)$ and pick the smallest value off the front of one, getting $(0,3,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,16,17,19,22)$  Your denominators are constant, so you just need to compute the numerators.

Comment: @RossMillikan The  goal is primarily to find an equation that can do it.

Comment: Do you want the denominator to be the least common multiple of 3 and 5? Or is it just there product?

Comment: @FareedAF Lowest common multiple

Comment: user553185  Do not vandalize your own post after having received an answer.  Upon posting a question, the question is no longer yours to vandalize, particularly after having received an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
This isn't an answer it is just a way you can think about it, and I am not sure that it will take you somewhere or not, but name the set $A=\{0, ..., b_1-1\}$
 and $B= \{0, ..., b_2-1\}$

And try taking the sequence $$x_{n,k}=\frac{b_1.n+b_2.k}{lcm(b_1,b_2)}$$
Where $n \in A$ and $k \in B$

Then after that take the $\displaystyle \min_{n \in A,k\in B}(x_{n,k})=x_{n_0,k_0}$ and you'll get the first elemnt you want call it $c_1$ (which is $\frac{0}{15}$ in your case)

Then exclude this element from the sequence (by excluding $n_0$ from $A$ and $k_0$ from $B$) and take the minimum again and so on...